# Why are RGB values of a PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb image only from 0 to 255?

Tags: c#

I have a short script that creates a bitmap copy of another bitmap and changes `PixelFormat` from `Format32bppArgb` (original input image) to `Format48bppRgb`. Then creates a list of `Red` values and outputs them.

`Format32bppArgb` uses `8 bits` per channel and `Format48bppRgb` `16`. But my red channel output values are between `0` and `255` for both formats, why is that so?

```
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(@"minibottle.png");
            Bitmap bitmapCopy = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height ,PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapCopy)) {
                gr.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapCopy.Width, bitmapCopy.Height));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Original PixelFormat: " + bitmap.PixelFormat); // Format32bppArgb
            Console.WriteLine("Copy PixelFormat: " + bitmapCopy.PixelFormat); //Format48bppRgb

            List<int> rPixels = new List<int>();
            for (int row = 0; row < bitmapCopy.Width; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < bitmapCopy.Height; column++) {
                    var r = bitmapCopy.GetPixel(row, column).R;
                    rPixels.Add(r);
                }
            }
            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmapCopy.Dispose();

            var str = "";
            foreach (int px in rPixels) {
                str = str + px + ", ";

            }
            Console.WriteLine("R values of all pixels: " + str);  // 237, 238, 238, 236, 232, 234,...
        }
```

Comment: Where would the extra bits come from?

Comment: I expected that when each channel gets additional 8 bits to encode more colors, the "0 red" will be on one end and “65535  red” on the other with many more in between. Is the 8bit red channel 255 not supposed to be 65535 in 16bit channel?

Comment: But the original image only had room for 8 bits of red, why would the copy have more? In other words, even if the new format allows for more than 8 bits of red information, the original can’t supply it... Maybe I’m misunderstanding the question; it’s been a few years since I worked with images at this level.

Comment: I am new to these concepts as well. I thought that the 255 possible red colors will be encoded with 255 numbers that are spread from 0 to 65535 with lots of empty color space in between since as you said, the original image doesn’t have the colors that the new has space for. Perhaps the 16bit encoding follows different rule and it reserves first 265 numbers for 8bit encoding.

Comment: Just a  FYI. `Color.R` (the thing GetPixel returns) returns a byte so it that function would have to downsample to represent any color, you may need to look in to using `Bitmap.LockBits` to get the actual raw values.

Comment: Using help, IntelliSense or a debugger would let you know the problem in a few seconds. **Use those tools.**

Comment: @HereticMonkey: it's true that the original had only 8-bits of color _precision_. But when the bitmap is copied, these values are converted to the new precision of 16-bits per pixel (well, actually 12 bpp because of GDI+ limitations). The new image will still only have the original 8 bpp of precision, but the values will be spread out more, with a difference of approx. 16 between each pixel value (it's not exactly 16, because the range 0-255 is being mapped to 0-8192, instead of 0-8191).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my red channel output values are between 0 and 255 for both formats, why is that so?

Because the method you are using to obtain the values, the `Color` value returned by [`GetPixel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel?view=netframework-4.8), cannot represent 16-bit color channels. Each component property of `Color`, such as [`Color.R`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.r?view=netframework-4.8) returns a `byte` value, which can only store 8 bits of data. So the internal pixel value of the bitmap is converted back to the 8 bits-per-pixel range that `Color` uses.

If you want to see the actual color channel values, you need to look at the pixel data directly. This is a better approach when dealing with a full bitmap's worth of data anyway, as the `GetPixel()` method is *extremely* slow. The `LockBits()` method will return a pointer to the bitmap data which allows you to look at the pixel data directly, and in a much more efficient manner.

Here is a version of your code that will return the actual color channel values for your 48 bits-per-pixel bitmap:

```cs
using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"minibottle.png"))
using (Bitmap bitmapCopy = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb))
{
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapCopy))
    {
        gr.DrawImage(bitmap, bitmapCopy.Size.ToRect());
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Original PixelFormat: {bitmap.PixelFormat}"); // Format32bppArgb
    Console.WriteLine($"Copy PixelFormat: {bitmapCopy.PixelFormat}"); //Format48bppRgb

    List<int> rPixels = GetRedValuesWithLockBits(bitmapCopy);
    Console.WriteLine($"R values of all pixels: {string.Join(", ", rPixels)}");  // 237, 238, 238, 236, 232, 234,...
}
```

where I have moved the bitmap processing to its own method:

```cs
private static List<int> GetRedValuesWithLockBits(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(bitmap.Size.ToRect(), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    try
    {
        unsafe
        {
            byte* ppixelRow = (byte *)bitmapData.Scan0;

            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                ushort* ppixelData = (ushort *)ppixelRow;

                for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    // components are stored in BGR order, i.e. red component last
                    result.Add(ppixelData[2]);
                    ppixelData += 3;
                }

                ppixelRow += bitmapData.Stride;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

and included a little helper extension method:

```cs
static class Extensions
{
    public static Rectangle ToRect(this Size size)
    {
        return new Rectangle(new Point(), size);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- You will have to enable the "Allow unsafe code" setting in the project settings (under the "Build" tab)
- You will notice that the values returned range only from 0 to 8192. One might expect to see values ranging from 0 to 65535, which would be the full range of an unsigned 16-bit value. However, in the .NET code you're using, you're using GDI+ as the underlying graphical support, and [it has this limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> PixelFormat48bppRGB, PixelFormat64bppARGB, and PixelFormat64bppPARGB use 16 bits per color component (channel). GDI+ version 1.0 and 1.1 can read 16-bits-per-channel images, but such images are converted to an 8-bits-per-channel format for processing, displaying, and saving. **Each 16-bit color channel can hold a value in the range 0 through 2^13.**
> *[Emphasis mine]*.

In other words, GDI+ allows only values from 0 to 8192 in the color channel. If you try it, you can determine experimentally that in fact, it in fact will also allow values from 8193 through 32767, which is technically 15 bits of color precision. But any value greater than 8192 is treated as if it were 8192. Values greater than 32767 will be displayed as black.

When GDI+ itself is generating the bitmap, as in your example, it will not use values greater than its documented maximum value of 8192.

Finally, it is worth emphasizing that this is strictly a GDI+ limitation. Windows offers other bitmap-handling APIs, and .NET's WPF bitmap-handling is based on the Windows Imaging Component (WIC) instead of GDI+. And WIC does not have this limitation. It handles true 48 bpp color resolutions.

Here is a version of the pixel-value extraction that uses the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` class, which is part of the WPF API, instead of using the GDI+–based API from the Winforms API:

```cs
private static List<int> GetRedValues(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    int ushortStride = bitmap.PixelWidth * 3, rowIndex = 0;
    ushort[] pixelData = new ushort[bitmap.PixelHeight * ushortStride];

    bitmap.CopyPixels(pixelData, ushortStride * sizeof(ushort), 0);

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        int pixelIndex = rowIndex;

        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            // In WPF's Rgb48 format, components are stored in RGB order, i.e. red component first
            result.Add(pixelData[pixelIndex]);
            pixelIndex += 3;
        }

        rowIndex += ushortStride;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Naturally, to call that version you'll have to use the WPF mechanisms for loading and converting the bitmap format. See the `BitmapImage` and `FormatConvertedBitmap` classes for more details on that.

If you convert your original bitmap to 48 bpp using the `FormatConvertedBitmap` class, and then pass the new bitmap to the above method, you'll find that the component values for the pixels range from 0 to 65535, just as one would expect for a 16-bit color component. Though of course, as noted previously, there will still only be eight bits of color precision, as the difference between any two closest color component values will be 257 (it's not 256, because that would leave a gap at the top, where the highest 8-bit color component value of `0xff` would wind up as only `0xff00`, instead of the actual max value of `0xffff` that is needed).