# Unexpected RGB channel values for gray pixel in 48 bits bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gdi+

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446921/confused-about-lockbits-bitmapdata-and-pixelformat-format48bpprgb).

I've managed to extract pixel informations off a bitmap instance using `Bitmap.LockBits`. `PixelFormat` is `Format48bppRbg` which, based on my understanding and [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68447836/848975) on the aforementioned question, should store each pixel's RGB color channels using two bytes for storage. The bytes's combined value should be equal to a number between 0 and 8192, representing an RBG channel intensity value. That value is obtained by passing both bytes to the `BitConverter.ToUInt16` method.

So upon extracting pixel informations for the following 3 x 3 bitmap (magnified here for clarity):

[image: bitmap]

I'm having first row of pixel channels going like this:

| Pixel color | Red intensity | Green intensity | Blue intensity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RED | 8192 | 0 | 0 |
| GREEN | 0 | 8192 | 0 |
| BLUE | 0 | 0 | 8192 |

So far so good.

On the second row, however, it goes like this:

| Pixel color | Red intensity | Green intensity | Blue intensity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WHITE | 8192 | 8192 | 8192 |
| **GRAY (!)** | **1768 (!)** | **1768 (!)** | **1768 (!)** |
| BLACK | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The white and black pixel channel values make sense to me.

The gray, however, doesn't.

If you use any color picker on the gray pixel above, you should get a perfectly medium gray. In 24 bits color it should be the equivalent of (R: 128, G: 128, B: 128), or #808080 in hexadecimal form.

Then how come, in a `Format48bppRpg` pixel format, the channels intensity is way below the expected, middle 4096 value? Isn't this GDI+ based range of 0-8192 supposed to work like its 8 bits counterpart, with 0 being the lowest intensity and 8192 the highest? What am I missing here?

For reference, here is a screen capture from `Visual Studio` debugger showing the raw bytes indexes and values, with additional notes on the stride, channels positions and their extracted intensity value, up to the gray pixel:

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part where you state an incorrect assumption is that #808080 is "perfectly medium gray". It is not, at least not if you look at it from a certain way (more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_gray)).

Many color standards, including sRGB, use [gamma compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction#Microsoft_Windows,_Mac,_sRGB_and_TV/video_standard_gammas) to make darker colors more spaced out in the range of 256 values normally used to store RGB colors. This roughly means taking a square root (or 2.2-root) of the relative component value before encoding this value. The reason is that the human eye (like other senses) perceives brightness logarithmically, thus it is important to represent even an arithmetically small change in the brightness if it would mean actually doubling it, for example.

The byte value of 128 is actually about 21,95 % (128/255 ^ 2.2) of full brightness, which is what you're seeing in the case of 16-bit components. The space of possible values there is much larger, thus GDI (or the format) doesn't need to store them in a special way anymore.

In case you need an algorithm, taking the 2.2-root of the value works mostly well, but the correct formula is a bit different, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation). The root function normally has an infinite slope near zero, so the specific formula attempts to fix that by making that portion linear. A piece of code can be derived from that quite easily:

```cs
static byte TransformComponent(ushort linear)
{
    const double a = 0.055;
    var c = linear / 8192.0;
    c = c <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * c : (1 + a) * Math.Pow(c, 1/2.4) - a;
    return (byte)Math.Round(c * Byte.MaxValue);
}
```

This gives 128 for the value of 1768.

Comment: Wow, this is so much harder than expected. My mind can't work out what to do next to convert each value back to its closest 8 bit equivalent. I'll try looking up examples of 8 bits / 16 bits RGB conversion algorithms. Perhaps with a few more example I'll have my eureka moment. If you know any online resources about that, please share. Thank you so much for your great, great answer!

Comment: @Crono I have added the code to convert back to the usual 8-bit value. ;-)

Comment: Yep, works like a charm! :D If I may dare burden you again, how would you name the 
number literals in your function, if they were variables? I'd like to work this information in the documentation.

Comment: @Crono I am afraid I don't know any proper or specific name for them. It's all part of the conversion formula.